# what can I say about the solution $y(x)$ of the ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be differentiable and satisfy the ODE:
$$\frac{dy}{dx} =f(y),x\in\mathbb R$$
$$y(0)=y(1)=0$$

where $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is a Lipschitz continuous function. Then

1. $y(x)=0$ if and only if $x\in\ ${$0,1$}
2. $y$ is bounded
3. $y$ is strictly increasing
4. $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is unbounded.

I've got this question from an exam paper, and I cannot understand how to solve it. How should I use the condition of Lipschitz continuity of $f$ to solve it?

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have to choose one among those four options? Prove that all of them are are true?

Comment: I've to choose only one correct option from the given four options.@AugSB

Answer (score 4):

You can try to prove that from the conditions and uniqueness it follows that $y(0+h)=y(1+h)$ and thus that $y$ is periodic (which would in itself imply boundedness and an infinite number of zeros). However, is impossible to get periodic solutions for an first order scalar ODE, except in for the trivial case of constant solutions.

Since by the assumptions the function $y$ is constant with the given value, the properties of it are likewise trivial.

---

*(from comments)* You have a continuous function (if there is a solution at all) on a compact interval $[0,1]$, thus it is bounded, independent of it being a solution to the ODE. If it is not the constant function $y=0$, it must pass through a maximum or minimum where $0=y′(x^∗)=f(y(x^∗))=f(y^∗)$. On the other hand $y(x)=y^∗=const.$ is also a solution, from uniqueness (using the Lipschitz property of $f$) you get a contradiction for $y^∗≠0$, as then no other solution can take the value $y^∗$. .

Comment: So, is the option 2 correct?@LutzL

Comment: Yes, trivially for $y\equiv 0$. But for that to be possible one needs $f(0)=0$.

Comment: @LutzL, am I correct in saying "Considering the case $f(y)=0$ (Lipschitz continuous), considering trivial solution $y(x)=0\forall x\in\mathbb R$, options 1,3,4 are wrong."

Comment: No, that does not parse. You have a continuous function (if there is a solution at all) on a compact interval, thus it is bounded, independent of it being a solution to the ODE. You solution must pass through a maximum or minimum with $0=y'(x^*)=f(y^*=y(x^*))$. On the other hand $y(x)=y^*=const.$ is then a solution, from uniqueness you get a contradiction for $y^*\ne 0$.

Comment: @LutzL Could you please tell me which existence and uniqueness theorem you are referring to?

Comment: In this case Cauchy-Lipschitz, which uses the maximum of the derivative of $f$on bounded sets as local Lipschitz constant. Thus local existence and uniqueness. $0=f(y^*)$ implies that $y(x)\equiv y^*$ is a solution and no other solution can take the value $y^*$. It follows that no solution has maxima or minima, all solutions are either growing or falling, making periodic boundary conditions impossible except for constant solutions.

Comment: @LutzLehmann how you prove that solution will be periodic by using uniqueness theorem? I am unable to understand it $y(0+h)=y(1+h)$ ? Thank you .

Comment: @neelkanth : For any autonomous system $y'=f(y)$, if $y(t)$ is a solution, then also $z(t)=y(t+a)$ is a solution. Now if both have the same initial values, $y(0)=z(0)=y(a)$, then the solution have to be identical if the conditions for uniqueness are given. Thus also $y(a)=z(a)=y(2a)$, $y(-a)=z(-a)=y(0)$ and so on, so that periodicity follows by induction.

Comment: @LutzLehmann thank you very much sir .... now i got it .